# Spring Boot & WinRun4J for Windows Service JAR: Service launch class outside BOOT-INF folder

Tags: maven, spring-boot, winrun4j

I want to run an Spring Boot Application as a Windows Service using [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/). It doesn't work since WinRun4J is unable to find the main class. I noticed that it is because the spring-boot-maven-plugin collect the sources inside a BOOT-INF folder and it can't access to the classes there. This is the error trace:

```
[info] Registering natives for Native class
[info] Registering natives for FFI class
 [err] Could not find service class
 [err] Failed to initialise service: 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SpringBootLauncherService
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SpringBootLauncherService
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

**Is there a way to generate the Spring Boot executable jar with the desired class outside the BOOT-INF folder?** Or maybe **do you know a full example using Spring Boot and WinRun4J?**

The generated jar by the spring-boot-maven-plugin has the following structure:

```
myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
|--- org: Spring Boot Loader classes
|--- META-INF: maven/ & MANIFEST-MF
|--- BOOT-INF: lib/ & classes/
```

And I believe that I need something like this:

```
myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
|--- org: Spring Boot Loader classes
|--- META-INF: maven/ & MANIFEST-MF
|--- BOOT-INF: lib/ & classes/
|--- SpringBootLauncherService.class
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work as follows.

- I used the bootRepackage classifier property to force Spring Boot to make 2 JARs: one with the Spring Boot structure, and the other a normal JAR that can be used for other purposes, like integration with WinRun4J for example. This is explained fairly well in [Use a Spring Boot application as a dependency](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar)
- I extracted the lib from the executable JAR and added the folder to the classpath in the INI file for WinRun4J. `classpath.1=the-springboot-app.jar classpath.2=./lib/*`
- Still in the INI file, I added `vmarg.1=-Dloader.main=the.springboot.app.Application` so that the `SpringBootLauncherService` class using the SpringBoot PropertiesLaucher can resolve the loader class.
- The service.class is set in the INI to `service.class=the.springboot.app.SpringBootLauncherService`

Comment: This being said, I also tried `winsw` and found it to be much simpler. It starts the Spring Boot application the same way I would on the command line, with `java -jar my-app.jar`. I would recommend it you take a look at it as a very good alternative to WinRun4J.  See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-windows.

Comment: You're exactly right about `winsw`. Worked like a charm for my app -- thanks.